# How to load Yii 2 fixture?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, fixtures, codeception

I use a simple fixture to populate the table in the test database. But when I try to load it, check integrity code throws exception 'Table not found: []'.

My fixture:

```
<?php

namespace tests\unit\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class IdentityDocumentFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'backend\modules\persons\models\IdentityDocument';
}
```

To load fixture, I use this command from @app/tests: `yii fixture/load IdentityDocument`

```
C:\php-projects\ais\tests\codeception\bin>yii fixture/load IdentityDocument
Fixtures namespace is:
        tests\unit\fixtures

Global fixtures will be used:

        1. yii\test\InitDb

Fixtures below will be loaded:

        1. IdentityDocument

Load above fixtures? (yes|no) [no]:yes
```

As a result, I get this error message:

> **Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Table not found: []'** in
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mssql\QueryBuilder.php:180

Stack trace:

> 0 C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(753):
>   yii\db\mssql\QueryBuilder->checkIntegrity(false, '', '') 1
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\test\InitDbFixture.php(94):
>   yii\db\Command->checkIntegrity(false, '') 2
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\test\InitDbFixture.php(76):
>   yii\test\InitDbFixture->checkIntegrity(false) 3
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\test\FixtureTrait.php(114):
>   yii\test\InitDbFixture->beforeUnload() 4
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\FixtureController.php(147):
>   yii\console\controllers\FixtureController->unloadFixtures(Array) 5
>   [internal function]:
>   yii\console\controllers\FixtureController->actionLoad('IdentityDocumen...')
>   6 C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 7
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154):
>   yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array) 8
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(91):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('load', Array) 9
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454):
>   yii\console\Controller->runAction('load', Array) 10
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(167):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('fixture/load', Array) 11
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(143):
>   yii\console\Application->runAction('fixture/load', Array) 12
>   C:\php-projects\ais\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375):
>   yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request)) 13
>   C:\php-projects\ais\tests\codeception\bin\yii(22):
>   yii\base\Application->run() 14 {main}

How to load fixture? The test database exists, the data sources are configured correctly.

---

[Update]

The real name of the table is `tbl_identitydocument`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_identitydocument](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FISID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_identitydocument] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the method `tableName()` of the model `IdentityDocument`:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%identitydocument}}';
}
```

Model code completely:

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules\persons\models;

use Yii;
use backend\modules\persons\Module;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%identitydocument}}".
 *
 * @property integer $ID
 * @property string $Name
 * @property integer $FISID
 */
class IdentityDocument extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%identitydocument}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Name'], 'required'],
            [['Name'], 'string'],
            [['FISID'], 'integer']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => Module::t('ML', 'ID'),
            'Name' => Module::t('ML', 'Name'),
            'FISID' => Module::t('ML', 'FISID'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Under the debugger I can see that method `IdentityDocument::tableName()` returns:

```
$tableNameTmp = IdentityDocument::tableName();
```

I see that `$tableNameTmp` is equal `{{%identitydocument}}` (*verbatim*, returns this string)

---

[Update]

Under the debugger I can see the following. In the class `TestCase.php` there is a method `setUp()`:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->mockApplication();
    $this->unloadFixtures();
    $this->loadFixtures();
}
```

The exception is thrown here: `$this->unloadFixtures()`:

[image]

At the screenshot it is visible that `initScript` referenced to the path `@app/tests/fixtures/initdb.php` *but there is no such file*.. Also the `schemas` array  contains a single element `""`.

---

[Update]

I used the instructions written by [@slinstj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479964/slinstj) here - [Run `fixture/load User` fails to load User data](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/172). In my local project (advanced pattern and MySQL rdbms) the fixture is loaded successfully:

[image]

Comment: Hi Aleksey, 
What is the real name of the table for `IdentityDocument` and what name is being returned by `IdentityDocument::tableName()`?

Comment: It seems right! I will give a shot... see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 - Check if you have set the `tablePrefix` param for `yii\db\Connection`:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_', // <<<<<<<<
    ],
],
```

Further infomation from [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$tablePrefix-detail):

`$tablePrefix`:

> The common prefix or suffix for table names. If a table name is given as {{%TableName}}, then the percentage character % will be replaced with this property value. For example, {{%post}} becomes {{tbl_post}}.

## OR

## 2 - Set a `dataFile` path:

According to [this](http://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/172):

```
// In your IdentityDocumentFixture, set this:
public $dataFile = __DIR__ . '/path/to/your/data-file.php';
```

Comment: You are welcome. Are your fixtures being loaded correctly when running codeception tests?

Comment: If so, please, look at this: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/172